# Check whether array contains array

Tags: javascript

Welcome,
I need to find whether array contains array
I tried two ways(`indexOf` and `includes`),but both returns a negative result.

```js
let myarray = [
  [4, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 2],
];
console.log(myarray.includes([4, 2]));//Returns false
console.log(myarray.indexOf([4, 2]));//Returns -1
```

I then thought of having a foreach loop,and checking the array(using `==`),
But for that even `console.log([4, 2]==[4, 2]);//Returns false`
Please Help-I know this is simple for you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `some` and `Array.isArray`. `some` will return true if any one condition in the callback function is `true` and use `Array.isArray` to check if the element is an array

```js
let myarray = [
  [4, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [2, 4],
  [2, 2],
];

const hasNestedArray = myarray.some(elem => Array.isArray(elem));
console.log(hasNestedArray)
```